# Jackson: POJO to be defined by either a JSON object, an Array of Strings, or a String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am looking at being able to parse several JSON formats using Jackson into the same following object:

```java
public class SpeechAction extends Action {

    public String[] speechText;

}
```

Knowing that my parent class is:

```java
public class Action {

    public String onCompletedEvent;

}
```

The formats that I would like to be able to support (for easiness of writing, as it will be written by people and not machines for a while) are:

**1. Simple String**:

```json
{
    "speech": <speech_text>
}
```

**2. Strings Array**:

```json
{
    "speech":[
        <variant1>, 
        <variant2>, 
        …
    ]
}
```

**3. Nested simple String**:

```json
{
    "speech": {
        "speechText": <speech_text>,
        "onCompletedEvent":<EVENT_NAME>
    }
}
```

**4. Nested String Array**:

```json
{
    "speech": {
        "speechText":[
            <variant1>, 
            <variant2>, 
            …
        ],
        "onCompletedEvent":<EVENT_NAME>
    }
}
```

Formats 1, 3, and 4 are successfully parsed using the following code:

```java
public class SpeechAction extends Action {

    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    @JsonProperty("speechText")
    public String[] speechText;

    public SpeechAction() {
        speechText = new String[]{""};
    }

    public SpeechAction(String... text) {
        speechText = text;
    }

    public SpeechAction(String text) {
        speechText = new String[]{text};
    }

}
```

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpeechAction.class, name = "speech")})
public class Action {

    @JsonProperty("onCompletedEvent")
    public String onCompletedEvent;

}
```

But I haven't been able to tackle Format 2. I get the following exception when attempting to parse:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.nerus.app.actions.SpeechAction` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (String)"{
    "speech": [
        "Hello there!",
        "Hey you!"
    ]
}
"; line: 2, column: 11]
```

I was able to support Formats 1 and 2 by using @JsonCreator annotations but 3 and 4 were immediately lost.

I explored the custom deserializer approach but additionally to not wanting to lose the advantage of annotations I failed to see how to do it in a way that will not prove repetitive for my parent's class "onCompletedEvent" attribute (as I have a good number of classes that inherit from Action).

Thank you for any lead!

Comment: Why don't you use the common JSON format "4" for all JSON input types?

Comment: Hi @Phani Kumar Yadavilli, thank you for your comment! The reason I am looking at supporting several formats (shorter formats that the full blown Format 4) is that for the foreseeable future those JSONs will be written by hand by people rather than automatically generated. Simpler to type is better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson API provides you a Generic object called JsonNode which can parse any type of JSON stream unless and until you are receiving a valid JSON input. Therefore, you can always consider seeing the JSON pattern 4 as the common JSON because it covers all the scenarios.

I strongly believe that there is a design flaw. Given the situation,I would like to approach this problem statement in three ways.

1. Having all the JSON's with a common schema as type 4 JSON mentione in the question.
2. Create POJOs for the 4 JSON schemas and mapping them using the `ObjectMapper` of Jackson API.
3. Mapping the input JSON to `JsonNode` using the `ObjectMapper` and find all the required fields. (This is the most Naive way of processing a JSON.)

Since, you have mentioned the reason in the comment i would like to show you the 3 way.

**Note:** I would not like to go with this approach personally. If I were you i will rethink my design and go with the first or second approach.

```
public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        String jsoninpt = "{\r\n" + 
                "   \"speech\": \"speech text\"\r\n" + 
                "}";
        String jsoninpt1 = "{\r\n" + 
                "   \"speech\": [\r\n" + 
                "       \"speech text1\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"speech text2\"\r\n" + 
                "   ]\r\n" + 
                "}";

        String jsonInpt2 = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"speech\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"speechText\": <speech_text>,\r\n" + 
                "        \"onCompletedEvent\":<EVENT_NAME>\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}";
        String jsonInput3 = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"speech\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"speechText\":[\r\n" + 
                "            <variant1>, \r\n" + 
                "            <variant2>, \r\n" + 
                "            …\r\n" + 
                "        ],\r\n" + 
                "        \"onCompletedEvent\":<EVENT_NAME>\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}";


        jsonParser(jsoninpt);

    }

    public static void jsonParser(String jsoninput) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonInputNode = mapper.readTree(jsoninput);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonInputNode));

        if(jsonInputNode.has("speech")) {
            JsonNode value = jsonInputNode.get("speech");
            if(value.isTextual()) {
                String speechText = value.asText();
                System.out.println(speechText);
            }else if(value.isArray() || value.isObject()) {
                Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> speechObjects = value.fields();
                while(speechObjects.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<String,JsonNode> speechObject = speechObjects.next();
                    String key = speechObject.getKey();
                    JsonNode node = speechObject.getValue();                    
                }
        }

    }
    }

}
```